# How to detect different json object?

Tags: java, android

If my query is successful then my php server returns json object like this

```
{"Success":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

if it fails the it returns jsonobject like this

```
{"fail":[
{"msg":"Fail reason"}
]}
```

i want to detect "success" and "fail" in android . 
I tried this, its not working, any better solution is welcome ...

```
JSONObject jsonResponse     
if(jsonResponse.getBoolean("orderid"))
```

Comment: use `jsonResponse.has("Success");`

Comment: It works . thanks ..:) . remember to post it as a answer so that i can accept .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the key you can:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse;   
if(jsonResponse.has("Success")){
  JSONArray data = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Success");
  //*********
}else{
  String error = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("fail").optJSONObject(0).optString("msg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(jsonResponse.getBoolean("orderid"))
```

to

```
if(jsonResponse.has("Success"))
```